Remove PWA and Service Workers from Android
I have a website that used to be a PWA with a service worker, but now it's just a normal website. However, when I try to add a shortcut from within Chrome to the homescreen, Android still tries to install it as an app instead of just adding a shortcut.
I've cleared the website cache from Chrome on my phone, but this behavior persists.
Why does Android 14 still think this website is a PWA? Where is this information stored, and how can I delete it?
I've tried everything I can think of, including clearing the cache and checking the service worker, but I'm still having this issue. Any help or guidance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
